# What event happen first window load or iframe load?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, onload

Is it guaranteed that window `onload` event happens after all iframes `onload`?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links **and sub-frames** have finished loading.